# find max of a array of structures

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures

I've been googling and searching about but have yet to be successful with this. I would like to know the max value in `a{1}` and `a{2}` each considering all the fields.  Similarly, I'd like to know the mean for each a, also considering all the fields.

```
a{1}.field1=[1:5];
a{2}.field1=[1:6];
a{1}.field2=[2:8];
a{2}.field2=[2:9];
```

I was hoping something below in a loop would work:

```
fn=fieldnames(a{1});
max(a{1}.(fn{:}))
mean(a{1}.(fn{:}))
```

I assume there is some super efficient way to do this that I am missing...Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each field in your struct is compatible with the max/mean functions, you can use:

`maxima(ii) = max(structfun(@max, a{ii}))

means(ii) = mean(structfun(@mean, a{ii}))`

Structfun returns the max/mean of each field in a column vector. The max and mean functions can easily be applied again to find the total max/mean. You may then run this in a loop for a struct array.

Comment: Thanks. This is nice and simple.  Would the nested cellfun solution be faster?

Answer (score 4):

First off, I think you mean to define a multi-dimensional structure:

```
a(1).field1=[1:5];
a(2).field1=[1:6];
a(1).field2=[2:8];
a(2).field2=[2:9];
```

(Note the round brackets instead of the curly braces. Curly braces would give you a cell-array containing two `struct`s). Now, the values you seek:

```
max_mean = cellfun(@(x)[max(x) mean(x)], {a.field1}, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Doing this, will give you the maximim and mean of `a(1).field1` in `max_mean{1}`, and the maximum and  mean of `a(2).field1` in `max_mean{2}`.

Doing this for all fields can be done by nesting the `cellfun` above in another `cellfun`:

```
max_means = cellfun(@(x) ...
    cellfun(@(y)[max(y) mean(y)], {a.(x)}, 'UniformOutput', false), ...
    fieldnames(a), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

so that

```
max_means{1}{1} % will give you the max's and means of a(1).field1
max_means{1}{2} % will give you the max's and means of a(2).field1
max_means{2}{1} % will give you the max's and means of a(1).field2
max_means{2}{2} % will give you the max's and means of a(2).field2
```

Play with these functions until you find something that fits your needs.

Comment: Rody, `max_means` individual vectors contain `max` and `mean` of one field vector, i.e. `max_means{1}{1}` do not contain `max`'s, but a `max` and a `mean` from `a(1).field1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You were right, I had multidimensional structure.   When does it make sense to use a structure array vs a multidimensional structure?